# Inverter um número de 3 dígitos em JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var num1 = prompt("Qual o numero?");

var unidade = num1 % 10
var dezena = (num1 % 100) / 10
var centena = num1 / 100


var resultado = unidade * 100 + dezena * 10 + centena

alert("O resultado da inversão é de : " + resultado);
```

Comment: Ainda esta dando err, resultado não bate

Comment: Cria uma função que vai conseguir inverter, iria comentar porem foi fechada a questão... = function invertNumber(number) {
  let str = number.toString()
  let aux = "";
  for(let i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    aux += str[i -1];
  }
  return parseInt(aux);
}

Comment: Apesar de "funcionar", eu acho um exagero (além de uma volta desnecessária e mais complicada) converter para string, para depois criar outra string invertida, para depois converter de volta para número. A solução matemática da resposta abaixo é mais simples - além de ser bem mais eficiente, veja: https://jsbench.me/e0l2g6h25f/1

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a divisão não é exata. Por exemplo, se o número for 123, a dezena será `2.3` e a centena será `1.23`.

Uma forma de resolver seria arredondar os valores para baixo, usando [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
var dezena = Math.floor((num1 % 100) / 10);
var centena = Math.floor(num1 / 100);
```

Assim, no caso do número ser 123, a dezena será `2` e a centena será `1`.

---

Mas em vez de pegar cada dígito separadamente, você pode fazer um *loop* por todos os dígitos. E para cada dígito, você multiplica o resultado anterior por 10 e soma o novo dígito, assim:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Qual o numero?"));

if (isNaN(num1)) {
    alert('Você não digitou um número válido');
} else {
    var resultado = 0;
    while (num1 > 0) {
        resultado = 10 * resultado + num1 % 10;
        num1 = Math.floor(num1 / 10);
    }

    alert("O resultado da inversão é: " + resultado);
}
```

Assim, primeiro eu pego o último dígito (resultado de `num1 % 10`) e somo ao resultado (como ele começa em zero, então `10 * resultado` será zero). Então na primeira iteração, `resultado` será o último dígito do número (por exemplo, se o número for `123`, `resultado` será igual a `3`). Em seguida eu divido o número por 10, arredondando para baixo (ou seja, o último dígito é descartado, pois agora o valor dele é `12`).

Na iteração seguinte, `num1 % 10` retornará o penúltimo dígito (já que o último foi descartado ao dividir o número por 10), ou seja, `2`. Então eu multiplico o resultado anterior por 10, fazendo com que `3` se torne `30`, e somo ao dígito atual (que é `2`). Assim, `resultado` agora é `32` e depois eu divido o número por 10 novamente, e seu valor passa a ser `1`.

Em seguida, o mesmo processo: `resultado` é multiplicado por 10 e se torna `320`, e eu somo o último dígito do número, que é `1`, resultando em `321`. Ao dividir o número por 10, o valor de `num1` passa a ser `0` e o `while` se encerra. No final, `resultado` será `321`.

Desta forma funciona para qualquer quantidade de dígitos, e você não precisa ficar criando uma variável para cada dígito.

Também incluí uma validação para o caso de não ser digitado um número válido.

---

E se quiser que funcione também para números negativos:

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Qual o numero?"));

if (isNaN(num1)) {
    alert('Você não digitou um número válido');
} else {
    var negativo = false;
    if (num1 < 0) {
        negativo = true;
        num1 = -num1;
    }
    var resultado = 0;
    while (num1 > 0) {
        resultado = 10 * resultado + num1 % 10;
        num1 = Math.floor(num1 / 10);
    }
    if (negativo) {
        resultado = -resultado;
    }

    alert("O resultado da inversão é: " + resultado);
}
```

---

Obs: Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Comment: Eu iria apresentar uma resposta mas a sua sua resposta responde bem o problema, também senti uma preguiça de juntar documentação e havia feito [esse algoritmo](https://ideone.com/bml1rm) que a final das contas julguei overkill para o problema do AP. Ficando mais fácil apenas dar +1.